# how to sort this type go lang

Tags: go, goland, golang-migrate

```
  common": [
          {
            "id": 17878,
            "name": "sk",
       
            "sort": [
                {
                    "key": "sort_order",
                    "value": "5"
                }
                {
                    "key": "promoId",
                    "value": "1"
                }

            ]
           }

             {
            "id": 17878,
            "name": "sk",
       
            "sort": [
                {
                    "key": "sort_order",
                    "value": "1"
                }
                {
                    "key": "promoId",
                    "value": "1"
                }

            ]
        }


        ]
```

```
type sSortdata struct {
    Key   string  `json:"key"`
    Value string  `json:"value"`
    
}
```

```
type Data struct {

    Id                int64       `json:"id"`
    Sort          []sSortdata     `json:"sort"`

}
```

I want to sort Data struct using using only sort_order type . sSortdata is not global variable .  How can do this easy way

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sort.Slice()`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Slice) function to sort a slice. Because that sorting callback function given by the application, variable scope didn't affect to the sorting.

run on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-sds73ssOKn)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type sSortdata struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type Data struct {
    Id   int64       `json:"id"`
    Sort []sSortdata `json:"sort"`
}

func main() {
    m := []Data{
        {
            Id: 17878,
            Sort: []sSortdata{
                {
                    Key:   "sort_order",
                    Value: "5",
                },
                {
                    Key:   "promoId",
                    Value: "1",
                },
            },
        },
        {
            Id: 17878,
            Sort: []sSortdata{
                {
                    Key:   "sort_order",
                    Value: "1",
                },
                {
                    Key:   "promoId",
                    Value: "1",
                },
            },
        }}
    
    fmt.Println(`before sorting := `, m)
    sort.Slice(m, func(i, j int) bool {
        var sortI, sortJ string
        for _, data := range m[i].Sort {
            if data.Key == `sort_order` {
                sortI = data.Value
                break
            }
        }
        for _, data := range m[j].Sort {
            if data.Key == `sort_order` {
                sortJ = data.Value
                break
            }
        }

        return sortI < sortJ
    })

    fmt.Println(`after sorting := `, m)

    //before sorting :=  [{17878 [{sort_order 5} {promoId 1}]} {17878 [{sort_order 1} {promoId 1}]}]
    //after sorting :=  [{17878 [{sort_order 1} {promoId 1}]} {17878 [{sort_order 5} {promoId 1}]}]
}
```